# How to set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, powershell, pipenv

While trying to create a venv for a django project while beeing in the projects dir using pipenv, I noticed that after installing django with pipenv (`pipenv install django`), pipenv sent a message:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Installing django...
[=   ]  Installing django...[packages]...
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
           Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Success!
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (99c4b9ec1b8891ff787677276760beb6d6d4919c55660da1c713682156a6086c)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a6086c)...
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

After this I ran the command (`pipenv --venv`) and got this message:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
C:\Users\User7G\OneDrive\Desktop\My code\My VSCode Projects\VSCode
```

I knew from the start that all my vscode projects were using the VSCode venv, however for this project I needed to make a new venv becaushe of the requirements of installing and running django.

How do I set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to create a new venv?
Where and how do I need to set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to, how do I set persistent environment variables on Windows? Or, how do I set environment variables to be used by VS Code specifically? I encourage you to use those searches to learn more.

In this case, I believe you can do

```
setx PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS 1
```

For VS Code + Python, there is also the setting

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

So you can create/append to an `.env` file in your workspace root directory that contains

```
PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to resolve this.
You can resolve this with:

> set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS 1

### IMPORTANT* (Duplicated lines on dependencies)  :

If it persists try to check your pipfile or the project list dependencies, this can happen when you have the same library in different lines to install.

that is, you are asking pipenv to install the same lib twice and it gets lost in which version to choose even if the duplicate lines are the same version

I hope to help you out !!!! Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).